# Создание объектов с одного класса в другом

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте, можно ли как-то унаследовать форму JFrame создавая на нем новые объекты не закрывая и не создавая его каждый раз. То есть есть у меня класс в котором создаются кнопки. Мне нужно что-бы эти кнопки создались на форме в другом классе где JFrame. К примеру:

```
public class CreatBut extends PaintBut{
    public void createButt(){
        JButton but = new JButton();
    } 
} // в этом классе создаю

 public class PaintBut {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
 } // в этом должны появлятся
```

Делал через

> new PaintBut

, но тогда приходится закрывать старую форму и создавать новую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно например

```
public static void addComponents(JContainer con){
con. add(new JButton());
con.add(чё то ещё);
...
}
```

потом используешь

```
addComponents(new PaintBut());
addComponents(new JFrame ());
```